# Como tomar valores de una pagina web en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Necesito tomar el valor del dolar, de una pagina web, ya que necesito que este constantemente actualizado, para multiplicar ciertos productos por el valor del dolar.

Por ejemplo de esta pagina:
https://www.precio-dolar.com.ar/

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es buscar algun api que proporcione esos datos y consumirlo, por ejemplo [fixer.io/](http://fixer.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos, Tutee.

La técnica que buscas se llama `HTML Parsing`, lo que te permite obtener los elementos de cualquier página web en el modelo `HTML DOM`.

En internet encuentras algunos `parser`, sin embargo estuve probando (ya que mi fuerte no es vb.net) sin necesidad de descargar nada y la forma en que funcionó fue utilizando un `WebBrowser` (sin necesidad de agregarlo al formulario).

Este es el código, al final explicaré algunos detalles:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim web As WebBrowser  'Aquí se declara el WebBrowser

    Private Sub cargarPagina()
        web = New WebBrowser() ' Se instancia el WebBrower
        web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True ' Oculta la ventana de errores si algún script de la página falló (de todas formas no los necesitamos)
        web.Navigate(New Uri("https://www.precio-dolar.com.ar/")) ' Carga la página web creando un nuevo documento HTML

        ' Este Handler permite continuar con el proceso una vez que se ha cargado TODA la página (ya que si no ha cargado lanzará un error)
        AddHandler web.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf cargarValorDolar)
    End Sub

    Private Sub cargarValorDolar()

        If (web.Document IsNot Nothing) Then ' En caso de que la página no halla cargado bien el documento
            Dim divs = web.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("div") ' Obtiene todos los elementos <div> de la página web

            For Each div As HtmlElement In divs ' Recorre la lista de elementos <div>
                Dim className As String = div.GetAttribute("className") ' Obtiene el atributo [class] (nos servirá de filtro)
                If className = "currency-field-result" Then ' El texto con el que se compara es el que muestra el valor del dólar en pesos argentinos
                    Label1.Text = div.InnerText ' Se obtiene el valor del dólar

                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Básicamente, lo que se realiza es un 'filtro' de búsqueda entre todos los elementos `<div>` que se encuentran en esa página web por medio del `className`
el cuál corresponde a: `"currency-field-result"`.

[image: img]

Acá te dejo el resultado:

[image: img2]

La desventaja que tiene hacerlo de esta manera, es que podría variar según la página web, tendrías que modificar manualmente la forma en que 'filtrarás' los resultados.

Comment: Buenas C. Rodriguez, probe el codigo y no me cambia el texto del label, me queda como Label1, queria saber si debo modificarle algo, o cual podria ser el probelma

Comment: Ya logre que funcione, era un error muy tonto. Gracias y saludos!

Comment: Hola, olvidé mencionar que debías llamar a la función, pero seguro te diste cuenta. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar un webservice de los que hay en la red, 
[AQUÍ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589748/currency-convertor-web-service) tienes un artículo hablando sobre ello, quizá sea la opción más sencilla y fiable.

Pero como veo que usas .NET también puedes hacerlo descargando el código HTML de la página que indicas mediante su URL y leyendo el valor de texto localizando la etiqueta que tiene el valor (que concretamente es un div que tiene esta clase "currency-field-result"). El único problema de esto es que cambien el código HTML de la pagina..

[AQUÍ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c-sharp) tienes un ejemplo de cómo descargar una pagina HTML desde su URL

Espero que te sirva